# What is the best situation with URLs when the domain might change

Tags: html, url

I'm building a website, however the URL for the website is likely to change.

How can I load resources in the front end if the domain and installation directory is likely to change?

Now that I'm starting to get deep into building the backend I have some issues.

The url is about to change, what do I do now?

I can use PHP to get the current domain and have a preset installation directory. Then load it from a variable every time I need to load a resource.

Is there any other solutions, what would you recommend?

I'm talking about resources loaded through the browser, not ones loaded through php.

Answer (score 0):

If the resources are housed under the same domain as your php app, you can simply remove the protocol and hostname from those links and let the browser figure it out.

If the resources are hosted on a different hostname (or via a different protocol - http vs. https for example) then your solution of using a variable is probably the best course.